# Laravel can't have the date in french

Tags: php, laravel, date, php-carbon

I use Carbon to parse a date from database and show it, but I need to show it in French.
I don't find any solution, I try to use

```
\Carbon\Carbon::parse($comp->date_debut)->formatLocalized('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A')
```

But the output is "ljS\ofFYh:i:sA"

I try to add this to my controller

```
\Carbon\Carbon::setLocale('fr');
 setlocale(LC_TIME, 'fr', 'fr_FR', 'fr_FR.ISO8859-1');
```

But nothing too, anyone have a solution ?

Comment: Do you have the localization installed on the dev machine / server?

Comment: Hm, i don't know but the diffInHuman function return a french output

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code you should add `%` characters to `formatLocalized` function:

In [Carbon documentation](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-localization) there is:

> echo $dt->formatLocalized('%A %d %B %Y');

as example.

Also make sure you set Carbon locale in valid place, for example in `boot` method of `AppServiceProvider`

Comment: The output still in english :/ (Friday 22 June 2018) with formatLocalized with the % and with the carbon locale put in the appServiceProvider